# Import&Export Sharepoint Lists / Deploy this with VS2010

Tags: list, deployment, content-deployment

I created a webpart which grabs content of two Lists in Sharepoint, is used as source.
Its working very well and i like the way users can change content. Is there an way to export my list-schema+content and deploy it somewhere else? I already searched for that on google but it seems nobody used lists as webpart-source before... I know that i could handcode the two lists with c# but thats way to mutch work in this case...

**Thank you**

Sven

Comment: Read twice. Haven't understood the question :( Probably you need to rephrase, or to illustrate your question with some screenshots/code... What schema do you mean? List schema, webpart schema, or what? If you need to export xml schema of webpart, you should switch to edit mode of the page, and select "Export webpart" from contextual menu of your webpart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to list configuration page, save list as a template, check include content and you will have a list template you can use everytime you want to create a new list.

If you want to create a new list in another site collection, go to list templates gallery, select the template you just created and save it to your computer. Then go to the other site collection and import it.

Comment: Thank you .. that worked... its not the nicest way.. I thought about doing this automatic, for more than 20 List's ...

Comment: I don't know another way to do it with more than one list at a time. Sorry...

Comment: Well.. i think hardcoding is my only option..

Comment: Check this, it could help (not tested): http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428301.aspx

Comment: Well the thing is - we also need custom columns here... so its not that easy... I did that now with saving Site as Template, Importing Template in VS2010, cleaning it up (ALOT!) and deploying it to another server.. It's really hard to get the damn Lists workin (Forms...) but it atleast does..